# localizedStringForKey:value:table: with CFBundleDevelopmentRegion

Tags: ios, localization

I have the following:

[image: lproj files]

[image: lolization in project]

And the CFBundleDevelopmentRegion is set as "en" in the Info.plist:

[image]

The default language is english and has all the strings. The swedish and french version are not complete and I want to fallback in english when a string is not localized in fr or sv.

Here's how I translate:

```
translatedContent = [[NSBundle mainBundle] localizedStringForKey:translationKey
                                                           value:nil
                                                           table:@"Localizable"];
```

When the device is in english, everything is fine.

However, when the device is in swedish or french, it works but the translation does not fallback to english if the key is not present in the sv/fr file. Instead, it fallbacks to the translation key.

I can't figure out what is wrong. Any thoughts?